# Links in view do not lead to current language content

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, navigation

I have a Drupal 7.50 site with menu and content on the left side and a list of nodes on the right side. The Menu has a language switcher. When language changes the links from the nodes on the right side are supposed to lead to the content in this selected language. However, they don't.

After selecting the content I can access it in different translations by selecting them from the language switcher, but the links do not change.

The view for the right side is setup with a hidden field containing "Content: Path" and another field where I rewrite result with "`<a href="[path]">...</a>`".

This already works fine on another page and I am out of imagination for possible reasons why it doesn't on this one.

I tried setting different values for language detection and selection, tried setting URL alias patterns and cleared cache a couple of times. Maybe I just didn't find the right combination of things to do. Can it possibly be an issue on my themes side?

Grateful for any suggestions.